# How can i send complete base 64 string of image to json request android

Tags: android

Complete base 64 string is not uploding to json request

```
Actual json request is:
{
"obj":
{
 "FarmerName":"abcd",
 "IdAgent":"123",
 "TPFileUpload":"_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkzODdASFx..............",
 "TPFileUploadType":"jpg"
}
}

But From code json request as follows:
{"obj":{"FarmerName":"","
 IdAgent":"",
 "TPFileUpload":"_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4

 Issues are:

1)json is not closed
2)base 64 string of image is not completely uploading to json request.
3)The parameter after "TPFileUpload" are not adding to json request because 
  of Base 64 encoded string of image.

 Service Request as follows:

  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  @POST("service/saveinput")
  Call<SaveInputResponse> saveInput(@Body  SaveInput saveinput);

  saveInput pojo class:

  public class SaveInput {

    @SerializedName("obj")
    @Expose
    private Input obj;

    public Input getObj() {
    return obj;
   }

   public void setObj(Input obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    }
  }

 Input class:

 public class FooInput {
  @SerializedName("FarmerName")
  @Expose
  private String farmerName;
  @SerializedName("IdAgent")
  @Expose
  private String idAgent;
  @SerializedName("TPFileUpload")
  @Expose
  private String tPFileUpload;
  @SerializedName("TPFileUploadType")
  @Expose
  private String tPFileUploadType;
  //Getters and setters of Variables...
  }
```

I have tried the request using retrofit library and also with volley library,but no result,can you please provide suggestion to upload base64 string to json request in android.and some times "/" is replaced by "_"base64 string of request...

Note:base64 encode string is too large i.e,more than 180 lines..

Comment: why are you trying to upload an image this way? why not just send it as byte array? do you not have control of the API?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using this. I add my code. May help this.

**01. First get your image and convert it base64.**

**02. Http request with Json format.**

```
[
  {
    "attachment": "Your base64 String",
    "clients": {
        "CLIENTS_ID": "18081000000120"
    },
    "projects": {
        "PROJECT_ID": "18081000000306"
    },
    "userCode": "18011000000027"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi,I'm converting image  into base64 using the following code:   public  String encodeFromString(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }

Comment: "attachment": "Your base64 String".Here You are getting complete base64 string in json request?

Comment: image = getBase64String(bitmap);
** Method **
 public static String getBase64String(Bitmap image) {
        String encodeString = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodeString;
    }

Comment: My Base64 string of image is to Too large i.e; more than 180 lines,How can I upload it?

Comment: first get your image and use my method then it's converted. That's it. and also no matter how many long this.

Comment: Hi,How can i remove backslast from json request..  eg:{"TPFileUpload":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAYEBQYFBA......}

Comment: How you removed blackslashes from "attachment": "Your base64 String"-- base string while sending json request

Comment: no need to black slashes remove.you can use my method. Which I was mentioned the previous comment.

Comment: is it work now?? If work, gives me upvote in my answer.

Comment: encoded as follows...by using your method LOG::::  encoded string.../9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQc,But When I send to json  request ,getting backslashes before forward slash as follows..{"obj":{"FarmerName":"nhjh","IdAgent":"578","TPFileUpload":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcU..."}} like this,How can remove backslashes?.from json request